# How to add fields to UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, web

So I've been working on a Django project and I've hit a dead end. Every time that I try to modify the UserCreationForm to account for Insurance ID and/or provider, I hit an error that says I cannot do this:

```
Unknown field(s) (Insurance Provider, Insurance ID) specified for User
```

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to add these Fields to the form without having to override my User class?

```
''' Form used in patient registration. Extends UserCreationForm '''
class PatientRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = EmailField(required = True)
    insurance_id = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Insurance ID")
    insurance_provider = forms.CharField(required=True, label="Insurance Provider")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "password1", "password2", "Insurance ID", "Insurance Provider")

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
           raise forms.ValidationError(
               self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
               code='password_mismatch',
           )
         return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.clean_password2())
        user.insurance_id = self.cleaned_data["insurance_id"]
        user.insurance_provider = self.cleaned_data["insurance_provider"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

''' This displays the patient login form. Unique because of insurance numbers '''
def patient_registration(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PatientRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_patient = Patient(user = new_user)
            new_patient.save()
            temp= Event(activity= '\n'+new_patient.user.get_full_name()+" has registered as a patient ")
            temp.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') # TODO : Refer them to there home page
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/') # TODO : Ditto ^^^
    else:
        form = PatientRegisterForm()
    return render(request, "main_site/patient_registration.html", {"form":form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly referring to the `insurance_id` and `insurance_provider` fields in your form. Change the `Meta` class to:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("email", "password1", "password2", "insurance_id", "insurance_provider")  
    # Note: the last two fields have changed
```

You will also need to have defined `insurance_id` and `insurance_provider` in your `User` model.

Comment: If you just want to add the fields to the django admin UserCreationForm you do not have to have insurance_id and insurance_provider defined on the model but can only add them to "add_fieldsets" in the Admin class.